# Self organizing maps

Tags: maps, self, som

I have question regarding the self organizing maps algorithm

I know that we have an input vector and weight vectors. The calculation of the min distance between the weight and input is the best match unit which make the weight column that relates to the min value update and then update its neighbors.After that we update the rate (assuming you have an experience in SOM).

example

```
input 
i1: (1, 1, 0, 0)

weight =
[.8 .4 .7 .3
.2 .6 .5 .9]
```

learning rate `.6`

**steps** (simply and dropping Gaussian function)

first iteration.

1- find the min distance

```
 d2 = (.2-1)2 + (.6-1)2 + (.5-0)2 + (.9-0)2 = 1.86
 d2 = (.8-1)2 + (.4-1)2 + (.7-0)2 + (.3-0)2 = .98   this is the BMU
```

2- update weight vector

```
new−unit2−weights = [.8 .4 .7 .3] + 0.6([1 1 0 0]-[.8 .4 .7 .3]) 
                  = [.92 .76 .28 .12]
```

the result of the weight is

```
.8   .4  .7  .3
.92 .76 .28 .12
```

**my questions**

1- at the end, I'll be getting new weight vector values and the same input vectors.

what should be plotted? Weight or input or what?

If am using matlab do you have any idea what function to use to get good illustration

Comment: if your question is only regarding plotting I redirect you to this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25258191/how-plot-u-matrix-sample-hit-and-input-planes-from-a-trained-data-by-som

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am learning `SOM` algorithm these days, and I am going to use `Python` to implement the algorithm, if you are familiar with `Python` I think you can click this link, [som_test](https://github.com/itdxer/neuralpy/blob/master/examples/sofm.py).

Your weight is

```
weight =
[.8 .4 .7 .3
.2 .6 .5 .9]
```

and you input value is

```
vector = [1, 1, 0, 0]
```

And I think the `output layer` is `2` because the `initial weight` is `2 by 4` matrix. And you can plot both the `input data` and the `weight`.

The input value is

```
[[0.1961, 0.9806],
[-0.1961, 0.9806],
[0.9806, 0.1961],
[0.9806, -0.1961],
[-0.5812, -0.8137],
[-0.8137, -0.5812],]
```

And the plot is, the weight is `3 by 2` matrix, as you can see in the image, there are 3 `X`s, that are weights.

[image: plot]

Answer (score 0):

Following you very simple example, the initial weights are:

> `Initial weight =
>   [.8 .4 .7 .3
>   .2 .6 .5 .9]`

and final weights should be (assuming all your calculations are correct):

> `Final weights = 
>   [.92 .76 .28 .12
>   .2 .6 .5 .9]`

Note that the winning unit - called best matching unit - is the only one that should be updated/changed here since you have disregarded the neighborhood learning aspect of SOM.
This becomes your results and is the one that will be plotted.